# subset working in a singular case but not when iterating over a data frame

Tags: r, loops, subset

I'm trying to subset my dataframe where the frequency of factor levels are more than 10.

If dogs is the name of a feature in a data frame:

Doesn't work:

```
somevar <- "dogs"
df <- subset(df, with(df, somevar %in% names(which(table(somevar)>=10))))
```

Returns df with 0 observations

Does work:

```
df <- subset(df, with(df, dogs %in% names(which(table(dogs)>=10))))
```

Returns df with a few less rows since those where levels of dogs with whose frequency are less than 10 have been removed

What's the difference and why does the second one work but the previous one does not?

Since I need to loop over features in a data frame, I need the doesn't work method to work! I want to pass a vector of feature names to a for loop

Reproducible Example:

```
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats")
df <- data.frame(vegetables, animals)
df
  vegatables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
4    carrots    fish
5    carrots    cats
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ vegatables: Factor w/ 1 level "carrots": 1 1 1 1 1
 $ animals   : Factor w/ 3 levels "cats","dogs",..: 1 2 2 3 1
```

I want to remove any observations where they are have a factor feature observation frequency less than 2. In this case frequency of level fish within animals factor is 1, so I expect the df to be reduced by one observation:

```
> test <- subset(df, with(df, animals %in% names(which(table(animals) >= 2))))
> test
  vegatables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
5    carrots    cats
```

Great.

Except it does not work when I do this:

```
categoricals <- names(df)

for ( i in categoricals ) {
  test <- subset(df, with(df, i %in% names(which(table(i) >= 10))))
}
```

returns an empty data frame df. I expected it to return exact same as test df above.

Similar:

```
i <- "animals"
test <- subset(df, with(df, i %in% names(which(table(i) >= 2))))
> test
[1] vegatables animals   
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I expected the last example to work like when I typed animals directly into with function.

Comment: I think the problem is, that you overwrite `df`within your loop. Therefore in the second iteration your `df`will be already empty. 
So store the results in other variables would be a solution.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminMohn, I added more to the question. It's not even the for loop. See "doesn't work/does work" above

Comment: @Hugh what do I do? I tried eval(somevar) in place of just using somevar but no luck

Comment: Can you provide example data and intended output? It's unclear what `df` looks like.

Comment: @hugh yes I have added that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be aware, that this approach will remove rows from both columns, as soon as one factor in either comes below your desired threshold.

```
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots","onion","onion")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats", "mice","cows")
df <- data.frame(vegetables, animals)

categoricals <- names(df)

for ( i in categoricals ) 
{
  test <- df[df[,i] %in% names(which(table(df[,i]) >= 2)),]
}
test
  vegetables animals
1    carrots    cats
2    carrots    dogs
3    carrots    dogs
5    carrots    cats
```

Comment: thank you. Why did I have to use df[,i] out of curiosity?

Comment: Extracting things in R is built around indexes. df[,i] utilizes this indexing function. df$vegetables or subset(...) does basically the same, but is meant for interactive use and will fail or produce strange behavior in any other application.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new data frame with the number of observations per animal, merge that data into the original, then subset in the normal way:

```
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats")
df <- data.frame(vegetables, animals)

library(dplyr)
n_animals <- count(df, animals)

merge(df, n_animals, by = "animals") %>%
  filter(n >= 2)

#   animals vegetables n
# 1    cats    carrots 2
# 2    cats    carrots 2
# 3    dogs    carrots 2
# 4    dogs    carrots 2
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh but I'm hitting the same issue as before. I can subset when it's just once with a given feature name. But not when I go through a sequence of features in a loop:
vegetables <- c("carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots", "carrots")
animals <- c("cats", "dogs", "dogs", "fish", "cats")
df <- data.frame(vegetables, animals)

library(dplyr)
feats <- names(df)

for (i in feats) {
  n_animals <- count(df, i)
  merge(df, n_animals, by = i) %>%
  filter(n >= 2)
}

Comment: Try `count_` and also review the documentation on NSE. `vignette("nse")`

Comment: Tried count_() but no success, even after fiddling with quotes "". I had this problem outwith dplyr too in my first attempt on this.